# Get product applied price rule by product id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

Simply I want to get the `rule_id` or catalog rule details that is applied to a product in product details page and product listing page.

I have checked with this function _getRulesFromProduct() from `magento-catalog-rule/Model/Rule.php` but it return all catalog rule applicable for that product.

I want only one rule which is currently applied to that product.

Comment: Did you pass all the arguments to the getRulesFromProduct function ?

Comment: Yes, 
$this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $product->getId());

Comment: could you share the full code you have implemented for this proces

Comment: public function get($product){
$priceRules = null;
$price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
$storeId = $product->getStoreId();
$dateTs = $this->_localeDate->scopeTimeStamp($storeId);
$websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
$customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
 } else {
 $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
}
$rules =  $this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $product->getId());
return $rules;
}

Comment: This is the code i have written. and return all rules which is applicable to the same product in product details page.

Comment: You need to get all active rules (or) only one active rule ?

Comment: Just only one rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way!

```
public function getCatalogPriceRuleProductIds()
{
    $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
         '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
    );
    $catalogRule = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
         '\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory'
    );

    $websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();//current Website Id

    $resultProductIds = [];
    $catalogRuleCollection = $catalogRule->create()->getCollection();
    $catalogRuleCollection->addIsActiveFilter(1);//filter for active rules only
    foreach ($catalogRuleCollection as $catalogRule) {
        $productIdsAccToRule = $catalogRule->getMatchingProductIds();
        if (in_array("Your currrent productId", $affectedProductIds)) {
            //product has a price rule set for it
        }
    }
    return $resultProductIds;
}
```

Please don't use objectmanager. it's bad practice! I hope it helps!

Comment: This function will return all product Ids applicable for the product right? i want the rule id

Comment: Yes! and using condition `if (in_array("Your currrent productId", $affectedProductIds)) {}`  you can match your current product id

Comment: The function i have written in the comment will return all rule ids which is applicable for the product. i want only single rule which is applied currently.

Comment: It is not necessary every product have a singe rule there will be multiple rules will be applied on a single product.

Comment: I have enabled "Discard subsequent rules" to yes in Catalog Price Rule from admin side. So i think only one rule is applied a product at same time right?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [rule_product_id] => 17 [rule_id] => 2 [from_time] => 1563148800 [to_time] => 0 [customer_group_id] => 0 [product_id] => 809 [action_operator] => by_percent [action_amount] => 10.0000 [action_stop] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [website_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [rule_product_id] => 417 [rule_id] => 3 [from_time] => 1563235200 [to_time] => 0 [customer_group_id] => 0 [product_id] => 809 [action_operator] => by_percent [action_amount] => 20.0000 [action_stop] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [website_id] => 1 ) ). 

This is the array which return in product details page.

Comment: No, I think `"Discard subsequent rules"` is validate when your product in the cart, but in product detail page it will display all applied rule which is relevant to your current product.

Comment: But only one rule is applied to this product currently. I can see the amount deducted (special price) after the rule is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rules from the `resourceModel` instead,

I have used `objectmanager` try to use it as dependency,

```
public function get($product){ 
    $priceRules = null; 
    $price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue(); 
    $storeId = $product->getStoreId(); 
    $dateTs = $this->_localeDate->scopeTimeStamp($storeId); 
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId(); 

    if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
        $customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId(); 
    } else { 
        $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(); 
    } 

    $resource = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');

    $rules = $resource->getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId,  $product->getId());

    print_r( $rules); 
}
```

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: In this function it will return array of rules. Not a single one.

Comment: share the result ..